# Show that $(\neg p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow (p\rightarrow\neg q)$ and $\neg p\lor\neg q$ are logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need to show that $(\neg p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(p\rightarrow\neg q)$ and $\neg p \lor\neg q$ are logically equivalent using only the logical equivalence laws, which you have to mention every time you apply them, i.e. without using a truth table.

This is my work below:

- Translation of conditional law $\equiv (\neg (\neg p) \lor \neg q ) \to (\neg p \lor \neg q)$
- Double negation law $\equiv (p \lor \neg q) \to (\neg p \lor \neg q)$
- Useful law $\equiv \neg (p \lor \neg q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q)$
- De Morgan's law $\equiv (\neg p \land \neg (\neg q)) \lor \neg (p \land q)$
- Double negation law $\equiv (\neg p \land q) \lor \neg (p \land q)$
- Distributive law $\equiv \neg p \land (p \lor \neg q)$

Comment: welcome to the site, please edit your post to include your attempt.

Comment: Thanks, done. Link is above

Comment: Next time, if you could put your work in the body of the question, either with an image that displays or with LaTeX, that would be simpler. Here's a guide to MathJax, which will help with formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last step:

> $(\neg p \land q) \lor \neg (p \land q)$
>
> Distributive law $\equiv \neg p \land (p \lor \neg q)$

is not correct. You could get $\neg p \land (p \lor \neg q)$ if you had $(\neg p \land p) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q)$, or with a DeMorgan: $(\neg p \land p) \lor \neg (p \lor q)$, but you don;t have anything like that.

So instead, from  $(\neg p \land q) \lor \neg (p \land q)$ continue with:

DeMorgan: $\equiv (\neg p \land q) \lor \neg p \lor \neg q$

Absorption [which states: $p \lor (p \land q) \equiv p$]: $\neg p \lor \neg q$

If you don;t have Absorption, you can do:

Identity: $\equiv (\neg p \land q) \lor (\neg p \land \top) \lor \neg q$

Distribution: $\equiv (\neg p \land (q \lor \top)) \lor \neg q$

Annihilation: $\equiv (\neg p \land \top) \lor \neg q$

Identity: $\equiv \neg p  \lor \neg q$

Answer (score 2):

From the very last step of your working, using distributive law,

$$\neg p \land (p \lor \neg q) \equiv (\neg p \land p) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q) \equiv F \lor (\neg p \land \neg q) \equiv  \neg p \land \neg q$$

Edit:

\begin{align}
&(\neg p \to q) \to (p \to  \neg q) \\
&\equiv( \neg(\neg p) \lor q) \to (\neg p \lor \neg q) \\
&\equiv (p \lor q) \to (\neg p \lor \neg q) \\
&\equiv \neg (p \lor q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q) \\
&\equiv (\neg p \land  \neg q) \lor (\neg p \lor \neg q)\\
&\equiv (\neg p \lor \neg q)
\end{align}

Note that in the last line, I used the property that  we have $A \land B \to A \lor B$.

Comment: I think the end result you came to is actually not what it asks for. I believe i made a mistake in the picture as well at the start. We are supposed to equate (¬→)→(→¬) and ¬ ∨ ¬. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How did you get from the second to last step to the last step?

Comment: I used $A \land B \to A \lor B$